# Is there a Necessity for private static Methods?

Tags: c++, function, methods, static, private

[The Principle Engineer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/201787/metal) at my last company had a rule that `private` `static` methods should be implemented as functions in the implementation file, not as class methods.

I don't remember if there were any exceptions to his rule. I have stumbled into the motivation for it at my current job: *If the arguments or return type of the function in question are objects that would require the inclusion of a definition file in the header, this can cause unnecessary difficulties.*

That's enough to steer me away from ever using a `private` `static` method again, but before I wrote them off I wanted to know if anyone is aware of a niche they fill that an implementation file function would not?

**EDIT:**

An example may be helpful here. Say this is the start of the declaration of `class Foo`, which has other methods which will call `void foo()` in the implementation file:

```
class Foo {
    static void foo();
```

So `foo` is only accessible by other methods of `Foo`. Why wouldn't I just define `foo` in the implementation file, and keep it out of the header all together?

Comment: @Downvoter Is there a reason for the down vote? Obviously if you're just providing the mandatory down vote on [tag:c++] questions, no need to respond.

Comment: So, how would that be different if the method was `public` or `protected`? The rule as cited in your question does not explain why `private` gets special treatment.

Comment: @ChristianHackl I assumed that was obvious. `public` `static` methods could be called outside the implementation of the object. Do you think I need to add that in for clarity?

Comment: I think you never need to include anything for a declaration, forward declaring the types should always be sufficient.

Comment: @Dan I had considered that, but I can't come up with a situation which would have access to the `private` `static` method would not have direct access to the `private` `static` data. Do you have an example I haven't thought of?

Comment: @nwp That's not always true. If I *want* to capture by value, or when I must return by value. In both cases I *must* include the object definition.

Comment: Are you asking about the benefits of private static member functions vs. free-standing functions in an anonymous namespace in the implementation file? `static` should not be used for free-standing functions anyway; that's what anonymous namespaces are for.

Comment: I use them for callback functions: function staticOnCallback ($user_data) {return $user_data->onCallback (); } There, it makes sense to have them in the class and not have them called externally. If the function needs to be passed or return an object then, in practice, it will need to know what it is so I'm not sure I understand the objection.

Comment: @Dan I've tried to clarify. Anything that would have access to `foo` would already have access to a `private` `static` member: `count`. Furthermore, I'm saying I don't think that we'd need to defined such a member in the header. I think that *it could also* be defined in the implementation file.

Comment: @Mike I'm not sure I understand your comment. Why couldn't an implementation function be used for the callback? Seems like it might be easier for you to explain in an answer rather than a 500 char comment. Since you seem to be highlighting another exception that I hadn't thought of?

Comment: @JonathanMee: Regarding the comment by nwp, returning by value does not require the type definition. A forward declaration is sufficient.

Comment: @ChristianHackl I've never heard that. I thought it was only references and pointers that could be forward declared. If you care to chime in I've asked for follow up on that here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/41966731/2642059

Comment: @ChristianHackl: [A forward declaration is not sufficient.](http://ideone.com/oIGwbj)

Comment: @user2357112: You need the definition only at the call site. See http://ideone.com/3yBY8R

Comment: @ChristianHackl: The type definition is available at the call site in my example. You also need the type definition at the function definition site.

Comment: @user2357112: But you do not need the type definition at the function *declaration* site.

Comment: @JonathanMee: it is possible to write it without any classes whatsoever but, from a design point of view, it's a question of where it belongs. A static callback may not have a $this variable but it is, nevertheless, part of the class. Functionally, it makes no practical difference but it keeps everything encapsulated nicely.

Comment: And this is why making broad, vague statements leads to confusion

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Member functions have access to all `private` members of the class. If a function needs access to these members, it should be a member. This applies whether or not it's `static`.

A `static` function is one that doesn't operate on a specific object. However, it can still receive objects as parameters. For example:

```
class A
{
    int m;

    static int process_3_objects_in_some_way(A x, A y, A z)
    {
        return x.m + y.m + z.m;
    }
}
```

Another reason to make a function `static` is the order of parameters. For example, `print`:

```
class A
{
    int m;

    static void print(std::ostream& stream, A x, int options)
    {
        stream << "Value is: " << (x.m * 1000000 + options);
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm guessing your second example should say `x.m` not `m`? Good examples though.

Comment: Just to keep poking, cause these are the best examples and I'd like my accepted answer to be at least compilable, I think you also wanted to have `print` return an `ostream&` right?

Comment: Yes, of course! That's what you get for not passing the code through compiler, I guess... (Removed the return value altogether though, to simplify)

Answer (score 12):

Unlike free-standing `static` functions in the implementation file, private static member functions can be used in the header of the class. This is important in situations when you want to inline a non-private member function, which calls your private static function:

```
class Demo {
private:
    static std::string sanitize(const std::string& name);
    std::string name;
public:
    Demo(const std::string& n) : name(sanitize(n)) {
    }
};
```

Doing the same with free-standing static functions would require implementing `Demo`'s constructor in the cpp file.

Comment: That's a fantastic example. So maybe the exception should be: "When the function isn't needed within the header."

Comment: @JonathanMee Yes, I followed this rule back in my C++ days. Something like "Prefer free-standing static functions and static variables to static member-functions and static member variables, except when you need to use them in the header of the class."

Comment: That is better said than my fumblings, as is clearly evidenced by the umpteen clarification comments on my question.

Comment: Couldn't you have just forward declared the static/free-standing method in the header file before the class? That should still allow implementing the constructor inline in the header.

Comment: ... though a free-standing method adds to the namespace outside the class. A private static method won't pollute the global namespace.

Answer (score 1):

`friend` functions or classes which are implemented in another implementation file are another example where a private static member function is required.

Comment: `friend` isn't really what I was looking for, but I suppose that is a fair example of an exception to this rule.