# Does my Return Type Need to be Defined?

Tags: c++, return-value, language-lawyer, return-type, forward-declaration

[Forward declaration](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class#Forward_declaration) lets us postpone defining an actual type till the implementation file. This is allowed in the header for pointers or references to a forward declared type.

[I have been told](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41964745/is-there-a-necessity-for-private-static-methods?noredirect=1#comment71111120_41964745) that:

> Returning by value does not require the type definition. A forward declaration is sufficient

Can someone confirm or deny this with an actual quote from the standard? I was under the impression that this was not legal.

Comment: Can you be clear what you think is not legal, exactly?  Like, an actual code sample you think is illegal?

Comment: That applies to function declarations, not definitions. And no, it isn't a quote from the standard.

Comment: Perhaps I should have said "Returning by value does not require the type definition **when you declare the function**. A forward declaration is sufficient." You do need the definition when you define the function and when you call it.

Comment: By the way, this applies to the parameters, too. You can try it in any compiler. I just struggle to find the exact confirmation in the standard.

Comment: _"Forward declaration lets us postpone declaring an actual type till the implementation file"_ No it doesn't. The clue's in the name; you're declaring your type right there.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Thanks, I have corrected that to: *defining*

Answer (score 33, accepted):

> Returning by value does not require the type definition. A forward declaration is sufficient

Declaring a function that returns by value does not require the type definition. A well-formed demo:

```
struct S;
S foo();
struct S {};
int main() {
    foo();
}
S foo() {
   return {};
}
```

Defining or calling a function that returns by value does require the type definition. Standard draft [[basic.def.odr]](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.def.odr#5):

> 5 Exactly one definition of a class is required in a translation unit if the class is used in a way that requires the class type to be complete. [ Example: ... [snip] ... [ Note: The rules for declarations and expressions describe in which contexts complete class types are required. **A class type T must be complete if**:
>
> - [snip]
> - 5.9 a function with a return type or argument type of type T is defined ([basic.def]) or called ([expr.call]), or
> - [snip]

The declaration of a function with incomplete return type is implicitly allowed by virtue of not being forbidden by any of the rules in the list.

The rule is re-worded later in the standard, and it is relaxed by an exception [[dcl.fct]](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.fct#11) (thanks to @cpplearner for pointing this rule out):

> 11 Types shall not be defined in return or parameter types. The type of a parameter or the return type for a function definition shall not be an incomplete (possibly cv-qualified) class type in the context of the function definition unless the function is deleted ([dcl.fct.def.delete]).

---

An ill-formed demo:

```
struct S;
S foo() {
    return {};
} // oops
struct S {};
```

Another ill-formed demo:

```
struct S;
S foo();
int main() {
    foo(); // oops
}
struct S {};
S foo() {
    return {};
}
```

Comment: Upvoted because this seems to be exactly the confirmation in the standard the OP was looking for.

Comment: Right. If you think about this from a compiler design perspective, it makes perfect sense: the type must be complete if the compiler needs to know its size/alignment. These do matter in code generation for expressions, and also in setting up the return structure for a function. But they of course do not matter for a forward declaration, which does not appear in the generated code and only updates the compiler's internal structures.